# About creating new elements in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, append

Could you explain about the following JavaScript code?
I can't understand it fully by myself.

```
function appendText() {
var txt1 = "<p>Text.</p>";              
var txt2 = $("<p></p>").text("Text.");  
var txt3 = document.createElement("p");
txt3.innerHTML = "Text.";               
$("body").append(txt1, txt2, txt3);     // Append new elements
}
```

Comment: It creates 3 variabeles holding the same element with the same text. Then all three are appended to the body with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see. Those were ways to create an element in JavaScript.

The first is creating by constructing the HTML string.

Second, it uses jQuery to create the element.

Third, it use the browser native document createElement method to create it.

All those three variations do the same things. Create an element.